# how to display values in JSON format?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

There I want to display the data in JSON format

> I want to display both if and else statement data in JSON format

```
        foreach($share_amount as $value)
        {
         if($value<$total_avg){
          $a= $total_avg-$value; 
          $data2['pay_amount'] = $a;   
          $data2['member_id'] = $detail;
          $data2['contribution_response'] = "Need to pay"; 
         }
         else
         {
         $b= $total_avg-$value; /* the share amount stored and calculated*/
        ....
         $data2['contribution_response'] = "Need to take";
         }
         echo json_encode(array($data2));  
         /*storing in json but not getting displayed in the format*/
```

Comment: give an example of displaying in json format?

Comment: [{"anytime":{"pay_amount":100,"member_id":"26","whom_to":"26","contribution_response":"Need to pay"}}]
[{"anytime":{"pay_amount":-200,"member_id":"26","whom_to":"26","contribution_response":"Need to take"}}]
[{"anytime":{"pay_amount":100,"member_id":"26","whom_to":"26","contribution_response":"Need to pay"}}]

Comment: I'm getting output in above format but when checking in postman it is saying unexpected error

Comment: Can anyone help me as to how to display the multiple data in single json format using json_encode?

Comment: once try echo json_encode($data2);

Comment: postman must be giving you error line or somethinbg?

Comment: i think you are passing a list of arrays to postman. [..][..][..]
but json structure should be {"item1":[...],"item2":[...]} or similar

Comment: So is there any way that I can display in single array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
This is how I got the answer
     foreach($share_amount as $value)
        {
             if($value<$total_avg){
                $a= $total_avg-$value;

        $data2['pay_amount'] = $a;   
        $data2['member_id'] = $detail;
        $data2['contribution_response'] = "Need to pay";
         }
         else
             {
        $b= $total_avg-$value;
        $edata['pay_amount'] = $b;   
        $edata['member_id'] = $detail;
        $edata['contribution_response'] = "Need to take";
         //echo json_encode($data2);

            }
            echo "\n";

        }
         echo json_encode(array($data2,$edata));
```

Answer (score 0):

**json_encode() example and Use JSON_FORCE_OBJECT:**

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

as per your code

```
## I want to display the data in json format ##
        $data2 = array();
        foreach($share_amount as $value)
        {
             if($value<$total_avg){
                  $a= $total_avg-$value; 
                  $data2['pay_amount'] = $a;   
                  $data2['member_id'] = $detail;
                  $data2['contribution_response'] = "Need to pay"; 
              }
              else
             {
                 $b= $total_avg-$value; /* the share amount stored and calculated*/

                 $data2['contribution_response'] = "Need to take";
             }
        }
         echo json_encode($data2, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);  /*storing in json but not getting displayed in the format*/
```

Answer (score 0):

There your code has an `array()` type variable which always reassigns to a particular value try to use `[]` for an auto-partition for new array value.

```
 $data2 = array();    

    foreach($share_amount as $value)
    {
        $tmp_array = array();
         if($value < $total_avg){
              $a= $total_avg - $value; 
              $tmp_array['pay_amount'] = $a;   
              $tmp_array['member_id'] = $detail;
              $tmp_array['contribution_response'] = "Need to pay"; 
          }
          else
         {
             $b = $total_avg - $value; /* the share amount stored and calculated*/

             $tmp_array['contribution_response']= "Need to take";
         }
         $data2[]['anytime'] = $tmp_array;
    }
    echo json_encode($data2);
```

Comment: Unexpected 's'... This is the error that i am getting when seeing in postman

Comment: can you share complete page code because the code does not have any 's' individual?maybe previous code has such error.

Comment: I'm unable to share the entire code. Can you suggest me some easy way to share complete code? -addy

Answer (score 0):

You need to build up an array of arrays - for each iteration through the loop you need to add the results as an array to the output object ( `$payload` ) and then encode that at the end.

```
$payload=array();
foreach($share_amount as $value){
    $data=array();
    if( $value < $total_avg ){
        $a=$total_avg-$value; 

        $data['pay_amount'] = $a;   
        $data['member_id'] = $detail;
        $data['contribution_response'] = "Need to pay";

        $payload[]=$data;
    } else {
        $b=$total_avg-$value;
        $data['pay_amount']=$b;
        $data['member_id'] = '';
        $data['contribution_response']="Need to take";
    }
}
echo json_encode( $payload );
```